# Exception in FluentProducerTemplate in Apache Camel after upgrade to 3.7.2

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I've the following dependency to 3.7.2:

```
<groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>3.7.2</version>
```

I've this in the code:

```
fluentProducerTemplate.to("direct:myenpoint");
fluentProducerTemplate.send();
```

This code was working until the upgrade, but now it throws:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No endpoint configured on FluentProducerTemplate. You can configure an endpoint with to(uri)`

Now I'm not able to figure why it's complaining about configuring endpoint as endpoint is clearly set in `to(endpoint)` call. I couldn't find anything in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that endpoint has to be set at `fluentProducerTemplate.setDefaultEndpoint(startingEndpoint);`

The error message was misleading. And, I am not sure why *to* (endpoint) is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fluent builder, so you should use it in a style like this:

```
template.to("xxx").send()
```